# pyspark processing & compare 2 dataframes

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, dynamic-sql

I am working on pyspark (Spark 2.2.0) with 2 dataframes that have common columns. Requirement I am dealing with is as below: Join the 2 frames as per rule below.

frame1 = [Column 1, Column 2, Column 3....... column_n] ### dataframe

frame2 = [Column 1, Column 2, Column 3....... column_n] ### dataframe

key = [Column 1, Column 2]  ### is an array

```
If frame1.[Column1, column2] == frame1.[Column1, column2]

 if frame1.column_n ==  frame2.column_n 
   write to a new data frame DF_A using values from frame 2 as is

 if frame1.column_n !=  frame2.column_n
   write to a new data frame DF_A using values from frame 1 as is
   write to a new data frame DF_B using values from frame 2 but with column3, & column 5 hard coded values
```

To do this, I am first creating 2 temp views and constructing 3 SQLs dynamically.

```
  sql_1 = select frame1.* from  frame1 join frame2 on [frame1.keys] = [frame2.keys]
  where frame1.column_n=frame2.column_n
  DFA = sqlContext.sql(sql_1)

  sql_2 = select [all columns from frame1]  from  frame1 join frame2 on         [frame1.keys] = [frame2.keys]
  where frame1.column_n != frame2.column_n
  DF_A = DF_A.union(sqlContext.sql(sql_2))

  sql_3 = select [all columns from frame2 except for column3 & column5 to be hard coded] from  frame1 join frame2 on [frame1.keys] = [frame2.keys]
  where frame1.column_n != frame2.column_n
  DF_B = sqlContext.sql(sql_1)
```

Question1: is there better way to dynamically pass key columns for joining? I am currently doing this by maintaining key columns in arrays (is working) and constructing SQL.

Question2: is there better way to dynamically pass selection columns without changing sequence of columns? I am currently doing this by maintaining column names in array and performing concatenation.

I did consider one single full outer join option but since column names are same I thought it will have more overhead of renaming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question#1 and #2,  I went with getting the column names form dataframe schema (df.schema.names and df.columns) and string processing inside the loop.

For the logic, I went with minimal of 2 SQLs - one with full outer join.